# Python 3: why tell() function after first readline() raises MemoryError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I have strange issue with Python 3.2.5 on Cygwin. I wonder if it is a Cygwin-specific bug, but I cannot check it now. After I read one line from text file, the next tell() raises MemoryError. Anybody can tell if it is normal behavior and why?

```
>>> f = open("file.txt","r")
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.readline()
'#!/bin/bash\n'
>>> f.tell()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>>
```

On the other hand, after seek() everything is ok:

```
>>> f = open("file.txt","r")
>>>
>>> f.seek(10)
10
>>> f.tell()
10
>>>
```

Comment: Works ok for me on Linux. Could be a cygwin issue! What are the contents of your file? `>>> f = open("/etc/passwd","r")
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.readline()
'root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n'
>>> f.tell()
32
>>> f.readline()
'daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin\n'
>>> f.tell()
80
`

Comment: simple, very short file (cannot paste with line breaks):
#!/bin/bash  \n   DEST=    # !!!!! put destination directory name here !!!!!  \n  1234567890  \n   ##################################

Comment: Works fine on windows (no cygwin).

Comment: Works fine on Windows. With and without Cygwin.

Comment: How long is the first line?